# `expr: non-integer argument`

Tags: command-line, bash

```
num1=20
num2=5
echo $( expr $num1 + $num2 )
```

I ran this code but it shows this error message.
What can I do to solve this?

Comment: works for me...  `num1=30; num2=60; echo $( expr $num1 + $num2 )` shows `90`

Answer (score 3):

Your script has the MSWin line ends (CR + LF). Run `fromdos` or `dos2unix` on it to fix them.

The values keep the `$'\r'` as the final character which isn't accepted by `expr`.